# How to compute SHA1 of an array in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, cryptography, sha1, digest

I'm trying to compute SHA1 of an integer array in the Linux kernel. I have gone through `crypto.c`/`crypto.h` and `security/integrity/ima/ima_crypto.c` but I can't figure out how to `init` and then `update` the SHA1 computer. Can someone point me to a tutorial or guide on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a pretty good introduction to the linux cryptography api in [Documentation/crypto/api-intro.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/crypto/api-intro.txt). Also check out [fs/ecryptfs/crypto.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ecryptfs/crypto.c#L95) for a real-life example of how the functions are used.

Here's a quick summary though to get you start:

### Step 1: Declaration

Create some local variables:

```c
struct scatterlist sg;
struct hash_desc desc;
char *plaintext = "plaintext goes here";
size_t len = strlen(plaintext);
u8 hashval[20];
```

- A `struct scatterlist` is used to hold your plaintext in a format the `crypto.h` functions can understand, while a `struct hash_desc` is used to configure the hashing.
- The variable `plaintext` holds our plaintext string, while `hashval` will hold the hash of our plaintext.
- Finally, `len` holds the length the plaintext string.

*Note that while I'm using ASCII plaintext in this example, you can pass an integer array as well -- just store the total memory size in `len` and replace every instance of `plaintext` with your integer array:*

```c
int myarr[4] = { 1, 3, 3, 7 };
size_t len = sizeof(myarr);
```

Be careful though: an `int` element generally has a size greater than a byte, so storing integer values in an `int` array won't have the same internal representation as a `char` array -- you may end up with null bytes as padding in between values.

Furthermore, if your intention is to hash the ASCII representation of your integers, **you will have to first convert the values in your array to a string character sequence** (perhaps using `sprintf`).

### Step 2: Initialization

Initialize `sg` and `desc`:

```c
sg_init_one(&sg, plaintext, len);
desc.tfm = crypto_alloc_hash("sha1", 0, CRYPTO_ALG_ASYNC);
```

Notice that `"sha1"` is passed to `crypto_alloc_hash`; this can be set to `"md5"` for MD5 hashing, or any other supported string in order to use the respective hashing method.

### Step 3: Hashing

Now perform the hashing with three function calls:

```c
crypto_hash_init(&desc);
crypto_hash_update(&desc, &sg, len);
crypto_hash_final(&desc, hashval);
```

- `crypto_hash_init` configures the hashing engine according to the supplied `struct hash_desc`.
- `crypto_hash_update` performs the actual hashing method on the plaintext.
- Finally, `crypto_hash_final` copies the hash to a character array.

### Step 4: Cleanup

Free allocated memory held by `desc.tfm`:

```c
crypto_free_hash(desc.tfm);
```

---

#### See also

> [how to use CryptoAPI in the linux kernel 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869028/how-to-use-cryptoapi-in-the-linux-kernel-2-6)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extremely detailed answer (as well as the customization). I will get to it as soon as possible and provide feedback.

Comment: I don't understand the rationale behind `sizeof(myarr) * sizeof(*myarr);`. `sizeof(myarr)` will give you 16 (assuming 32bit ints) and `sizeof(*myarr)` will give you 4. If you multiply them, it will give 64 which is definitely not the size of your array.

Comment: @tangrs Oops, looks like I made an error (you only need `sizeof(myarr)`); I'll correct it in the answer.

Comment: The output of `crypto_hash_final()` is 20-byte binary, not hexadecimal ASCII, so the size of `hashtext` should be 20, not 41.

Comment: @WuYongzheng Thanks for catching that error; I've updated the answer now to reflect the correct 20-byte binary size.